# when the Intent startActivity, how to stop the timer on android?

Tags: android, timer

when I app start, start `A` timer.

Timer execute every 5 second.

Question is:

> how to stop timer, when I start new Activity?

Here is what I have tried so far -

```
 public boolean isDevDetect;

 Timer timer = new Timer();
 final TimerTask devTimertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (//device detect) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                isDevDetect = true;
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "timer timer timer");
            }
        }
    };
    if (!isDevDetect) {
        Log.d(TAG, "repetition timer");

        devTimer.schedule(devTimertask, 3000, 5000);
    } else if (isDevDetect) {
        devTimertask.cancel();
        devTimer.cancel();
        Log.d(TAG, "stop timer");
    }
```

this source when connected device. start B class.
but timer not stop.

how to when start activity, stop timer?

thanks.

Comment: the value of isDevDetect not assigned

Comment: Edited few sentences for clear understanding...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean isDevDetect;

 Timer timer = new Timer();
 final TimerTask devTimertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (//device detect) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                devTimertask.cancel();
                devTimer.cancel();
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "timer timer timer");
            }
        }
    };
    devTimer.schedule(devTimertask, 3000, 5000);
```

According to what you stated let me rewrite the problem statement , bascially you are trying to stop the timeTask as soon as the startActivity is called.The above code will suffice your problem statement.basically you need to stop timer when startActivity is called.Hope this solved your problem.

------------------- **

### UPDATE

** -----------------

Please read the below blog , your `Timertask` is initialized .onRun() would be called only after  `devTimer.schedule(devTimertask, 3000, 5000);` after which your Timertask is initialized .
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html

Comment: thanks, but occur 1 problem.  `devTimertask.cancel();` is variable `devTimertask` might not have been initialized message.

Comment: initialized message ?? what does this mean

Comment: I would highly recommend you to read TimeTask and Timer . your onRun() method is called after you trigger devTimer.schedule(devTimertask, 3000, 5000);

Comment: `devTimertask` is not have been initialized. how to initialized?